# Must I always make sure with some function that the DOM will be completed for then executing the JS code?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am learning about events in JavaScript, following the official documentation, where the first example is:
HTML:

```
<button>Change color</button>
```

JS:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
function random(number) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (number+1));
}
btn.onclick = function() {
console.log("Oprimieron el boton");
const rndCol = 'rgb(' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ')';
document.body.style.backgroundColor = rndCol;
```

The previous code does not work unless you use an event for when the DOM is loaded completely, the error is:
DOM.HTML: 11 Uncaught Typeerror: Cannot Set Properties of Null (setting 'onclick') (my JS file is called Dom). Investigating I found that it may be because the DOM has not been generated when the script declares and uses the constant obtained by the Dom button. To fix the error use:
window.onload = function () {
}
Inside her I put the example code, the error is solved, the question is, must I always make sure with some function that the DOM will be completed for then executing the JS code?

Comment: You have to wait for the DOM *when the code depends on things in the DOM*. There is no single answer; it depends on your application.

Comment: always try to add a script at the bottom of the web-page